# What is the difference between b'' and '' in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a python newbie and I'm a little bit confused about the difference about `b''` and `''`.

I think they are both empty but `b'' == ''` returns `False`. But why? Can somebody explain this to me in terms of *memory*?

Are they the same in terms of content in memory and different in terms of type which results in inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b""` creates a `bytes` object while `""` creates a `str` object. To quote the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

> Bytes literals are always prefixed with `'b'` or `'B'`; they produce an
>   instance of the [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#bytes) type instead of the [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str) type. They may only
>   contain ASCII characters; bytes with a numeric value of 128 or greater
>   must be expressed with escapes.

In Python3, objects of different types (except different numeric types) never compare equal.

BTW, the memory size of the objects differs as well:

```
>>> from sys import getsizeof 
>>> getsizeof(b"")
33
>>> getsizeof("")
49
```

Answer (score 2):

(this is for python3): one of your examples is of the type `bytes`; the other `str`. they will never be considered equal.

```
print(type(b'')) # -> <class 'bytes'>
print(type(''))  # -> <class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

In python2 there is basically no difference. In python3 the first one is a string of bytes or a byte litteral, and the second one is a normal string.